# Shared memory doesn't work for a struct but works for a char*

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, shared-memory

This bug has taken too much hours for me and I simply can't find out what's wrong.

**Using the shared memory I created for a char * works perfectly, but when I try to use it for my created struct it doesn't.**

The language is C.

### Goal

The goal is to create a thread that sends data to a second thread (created by the first). The data is held on a struct called CircularQueue and must be passed using shared memory.

Also, the first thread must not wait for the second thread, it can end as soon as the second thread receives the name of the shared memory that was sent as an argument.

### CircularQueue

Personally, I don't think the problem is here, since it works perfectly (At least until now that I have started to work with the shared memory).

The CircularQueue is a structure that limits the ammount of the data and it uses semaphores and mutexes in order to do so. The semaphore makes a producer wait if the Queue is full, and the consumer wait if the Queue is empty. It uses a mutex so only 1 writes on it at a time.

### Problem

If I change the "CircularQueue *" to "char *", the sizeof(CircularQueue) to sizeof(char)*NUMBER_OF_CHARS and write on it on the first thread, I'm able to read it on the second thread.
But using CircularQueue is doesn't.

### Main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "CircularQueue.h"

typedef struct {
    char *v;
    sem_t sem;
} sharedMemoryName;

void * readThread(void * arg)
{
    // This first 3 lines is to get the name of the shared memory from the argument
    sharedMemoryName shm_name = *(sharedMemoryName *)arg;
    sem_post(&((*(sharedMemoryName *)arg).sem));
    printf("shm_name_2:%s:\n",shm_name.v);

    // This 2 lines open the shared memory
    int shmfd = shm_open(shm_name.v,O_RDWR,0600);
    if (shmfd<0) { perror("READER failure in shm_open()"); exit(1); }

    // This 2 lines attach the region of the virtual memory to the pointer
    CircularQueue *q = (CircularQueue *) mmap(0,sizeof(CircularQueue),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shmfd,0); //attach this region to virtual memory
    if (q == MAP_FAILED) { perror("READER failure in mmap()"); exit(2); }

    queue_print(q);   // Prints all the data of the CircularQueue (For Debug purposes)

    // Closes the virtual memory
    if (munmap(q,sizeof(CircularQueue)) < 0) { perror("READER failure in munmap()"); exit(4); } //unmap shared memory region
    if (shm_unlink(shm_name.v) < 0) { perror("READER failure in shm_unlink()"); exit(6); }

    return NULL;
}

void * writeThread(void * arg)
{
    // This first 4 lines is just for the name of the shared memory
    sharedMemoryName shm_name;
    snprintf(shm_name.v, sizeof shm_name.v, "%s%d", "/shm", 100);
    printf("shm_name_1:%s:\n",shm_name.v);
    sem_init(&(shm_name.sem), 0, 0);

    // This 3 lines create the shared memory
    int shmfd = shm_open(shm_name.v,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0600);
    if (shmfd<0) { perror("WRITER failure in shm_open()"); exit(1); }
    if (ftruncate(shmfd,sizeof(CircularQueue)) < 0) { perror("WRITER failure in ftruncate()"); exit(2); }

    // This 2 lines attach the region of the virtual memory to the pointer
    CircularQueue *q = (CircularQueue *) mmap(0,sizeof(CircularQueue),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shmfd,0); //attach this region to virtual memory
    if (q == MAP_FAILED) { perror("WRITER failure in mmap()"); exit(3); }

    queue_init(&q,4);   // Initializes the CircularQueue
    queue_put(q,1,2);   // Puts the value 1 on the CircularQueue
    queue_print(q);     // Prints all the data of the CircularQueue (For Debug purposes)

    // Creates the next thread
    pthread_t nt;
    pthread_create(&nt, NULL, readThread, &shm_name);

    // Waits for the second thread (Reader) to read the argument, so it can end
    sem_wait(&(shm_name.sem));
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL); // This is to avoid buffering in printf, therefore it prints immediatly
    pthread_t nt;
    pthread_create(&nt, NULL, writeThread, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

### CircularQueue File

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
typedef unsigned long QueueElem;
typedef struct
{
    QueueElem *v;       // pointer to the queue buffer
    unsigned int capacity;  // queue capacity
    unsigned int first; // head of the queue
    unsigned int last;  // tail of the queue
    sem_t empty;        // semaphores and mutex for implementing the
    sem_t full;     // producer-consumer paradigm
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} CircularQueue;
void queue_init(CircularQueue **q, unsigned int capacity)
{
    *q = (CircularQueue *) malloc(sizeof(CircularQueue));
    sem_init(&((*q)->empty), 0, capacity);
    sem_init(&((*q)->full), 0, 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&((*q)->mutex), NULL);
    (*q)->v = (QueueElem *) malloc(capacity * sizeof(QueueElem));
    (*q)->capacity = capacity;
    (*q)->first = 0;
    (*q)->last = -1;
}
void queue_print(CircularQueue *q)
{
    int fullValue;
    sem_getvalue(&(q->full),&fullValue);
    if (fullValue!=0) {
        int i, emptyValue;
        if (q->first <= q->last) {
            for (i=q->first;i <= q->last;i++)
                printf("|%d:%d",i,(int)q->v[i]);
        } else {
            for (i=q->first;i < q->capacity;i++)
                printf("|%d:%d",i,(int)q->v[i]);
            for (i=0;i <= q->last;i++)
                printf("|%d:%d",i,(int)q->v[i]);
        }

        sem_getvalue(&(q->empty),&emptyValue);
        if (emptyValue==0)
            printf(" [FULL]");
    }
    else {
        printf("[EMPTY]");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
void queue_put(CircularQueue *q, QueueElem value, int n)
{
    sem_wait(&(q->empty));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(q->mutex));
    q->last++;
    if ((q->last) >= (q->capacity))
        q->last = 0;
    q->v[q->last] = value;
    sem_post(&(q->full));
        printf("[%d]",n); queue_print(q);   // FOR DEBUG
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(q->mutex));
}
QueueElem queue_get(CircularQueue *q, int n)
{
    QueueElem elem;
    sem_wait(&(q->full));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(q->mutex));
    elem = q->v[q->first];
    q->first++;
    if ((q->first) >= (q->capacity))
        q->first = 0;
    sem_post(&(q->empty));
        printf("[%d]",n); printf("(GET:%d)",(int)elem); // FOR DEBUG
        queue_print(q);                 // FOR DEBUG
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(q->mutex));
    return elem;
}
void queue_destroy(CircularQueue *q)
{
    free(q->v);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(q->mutex));
    sem_destroy(&(q->full));
    sem_destroy(&(q->empty));
    free(q);
}
```

### Console output (printf)

```
shm_name_1:/shm100:
[2]|0:1               // This is printed by the queue_put(), when the first thread puts "1" in the queue (The 2, which is the 3rd argument of the function, is just for debug, this way I can see who wrote)
|0:1                  // This is printed by the first thread using queue_print()
shm_name_2:/shm100:   // The shared memory name is successfully passed
[EMPTY]               // This is printed by the second thread using queue_print()
```

**Thank you for your time.**

Comment: why are you using shared memory for this? threads all exist in the same address space, you only need to use semaphores to make access to the data thread safe.

Comment: According to the manuals:
A POSIX shared memory object is in effect a handle which can be used by *unrelated processes* to mmap(2) the same region of shared memory.
(i.e. a shared memory should be used between processes, not threads)

Comment: Mgetz and Levente Kurusa, the shared memory is required in the project and for this exact function (Passing the CircularQueue). I actually completed the project without shared memory and then I saw this requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `queue_init()` you are doing

```
*q = (CircularQueue *) malloc(sizeof(CircularQueue));
```

This overrides the shared memory address that you retrieved in writer thread by `mmap()`.

So `q` points to new `malloc`ed memory instead of shared memory.

Don't think you should `malloc()` for queue.

Also, you should use shared memory for `(*q)->v` rather than allocating as

```
 (*q)->v = (QueueElem *) malloc(capacity * sizeof(QueueElem));
```

If you `malloc()` and use the shared memory in multiple processes, `(*q)->v` will not be valid in other processes and may crash.

Comment: I use multiple threads, this is a simplified version I created to try to solve the problem. How should I use the shared memory then? How can I define the capacity of the CircularQueue array?

Comment: @Edu, You should add `capacity * sizeof(QueueElem)` to shared memory you want to create and assign appropriate address to `q->v` to store those elements. As others pointed out if you are using threads, you don't need shared memory.

Comment: Do I need to create another shared memory or can I use the same? I need to use shared memory because it is required in the project and for this exact function (Passing the CircularQueue).